# Why the loop is not breaking after first iteration .Expected answer is [1,3]

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

I have this code:

```
def num(list, target):
    index = []
    for i in list:
        for x in list:
            if i + x == target:
                index.append(list.index(i))
                index.append(list.index(x))
                break
    print(index)

li = [1, 7, 11, 2, 15]
num(li, 9)
```

I expected to get `[1,3]`, but the result is `[1,3,3,1]`. Why?

Comment: perhaps try printing what `i` and `x` are during the loop, might be a helpful debugging step.

Comment: It `break`s the `for x in list` loop, but not the `for i in list` loop. As an aside, you should use a different name instead of `list`; that hides the built-in name.